# Python: Nonlinear optimisation with restrictions (Gekko?)

Tags: python, optimization, gekko, restriction, nonlinear-functions

I'd like to be able to solve the following problem in Python:

Given observed data x(1)....x(n) and a known fixed target 'B' and tolerance 'E', solve for parameters a0, a1, & a2, which minimise:

sum(w(i)^2)

where w(i)=exp[a0+a1*x(i)+a2*x(i)^2]

with the following two restrictions:

1. sum(w(i)) = n , i.e. the mean of the w(i) equals 1
2. abs[sum(w(i)*x(i)/n) - B] < E, i.e. the weight mean of the x(i) is within a distance 'E' of target 'B'.

I've tried using Gekko and Optimise packages for quite a few weeks now, but I'm a Python newbie and am really struggling. Repeated attempts using ChatGPT have not helped either.

Any help gratefully received!

Kind regards,
Jonathan

Answer (score 0):

Here is a potential solution.

```py
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
x = np.array([1,2,5,3,2.7,5.1,2.5]); n = len(x)
a = m.Array(m.Var,3,lb=-100,ub=100)
w = np.array([m.Intermediate(m.exp(a[0]+a[1]*x[i]\
                                   +a[2]*x[i]**2))
                  for i in range(n)])
B = 3.1
E = 0.08
Ec = m.Intermediate(m.sum(w*x)/n-B)
m.Equation(m.abs3(Ec)<E)
m.Equation(m.sum(w)==n)
m.Minimize(m.sum(w**2))
m.solve()
```

This solves in one iteration with the APOPT solver. It will have a different solution with new data, target, and tolerance values.

```
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :  0.023999999999999997 sec
 Objective      :  6.999999999999998
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
```

Here is code to show the solution:

```py
print('-'*10)
for i in range(3):
    print(f'a{i}={a[i].value[0]:.3g}')
print('-'*10)
for i in range(n):
    print(f'w{i}={w[i].value[0]:.3g}')
print('-'*10)
print(f'Ec={Ec.value[0]} E={E}')
print('-'*10)
```

The results show that all constraints are satisfied.

```
----------
a0=-7.38e-09
a1=4.91e-09
a2=-6.73e-10
----------
w0=1
w1=1
w2=1
w3=1
w4=1
w5=1
w6=1
----------
Ec=-0.057142856157 E=0.08
----------
```

If there is an infeasible solution, minimize E instead of setting a hard limit.

```py
# E = 0.08
E = m.Var(lb=0,ub=10)
m.Minimize(1e-4*E)
```

You could also try using the square of both sides of the equation (to remove the abs value).

```py
m.Equation(Ec<E**2)
```

This avoids the binary variable that requires the APOPT solver. With squaring both sides of the equation, you can switch to the IPOPT solver with `m.options.SOLVER=3` or just use the default option in Gekko.

Comment: Hi John, many thanks for wading into this so quickly! Looking at your suggested code it's unclear to me where it minimises the sum of the w**2 terms. Happy to have your thoughts on that. Kind regards, Jonathan

Comment: Thank - I missed that part of the problem statement. I'll revise the answer.

Comment: Hi John, The addition of this code seems to work: 
m.Equation(m.sum(w)==n)
m.Minimize(m.sum(w**2))

Comment: Hi John et al, The code works but am hitting problem when 'n' is large, e.g. 500+. I get an "Exception: @error: Max Equation Length" error. Is there any way around this? Many thanks for any help.....!

Comment: Try using `m.sum()` instead of `sum()` or use `wx = [w[i]*x[i] for i in range(n)]` and `Ec = m.Intermediate(m.sum(wx)/n-B)`. Does that help? If it doesn't help, could you ask another question with that specific error?

Comment: Hi John, is there are way to specify an additional constraint on the 'w[i]', such that the maximum w[i] is less than a constant, e.g. m.Equation(m.max(w)<2)  ? I;ve tried quite a few lines of code, but no luck so far. Many thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Could you create a new question with a minimal example that shows your best attempt and the error?

Comment: Hi John, Here is my best attempt: w = [m.Intermediate(m.exp(a0+a1*x1[i]+a2*x1[i]**2+a3*x1[i]**3+a4*x1[i]**4+b1*x2[i])) for i in range(n)]
w2 = [w[i]**2 for i in range(n)]
wx1 = [w[i]*x1[i] for i in range(n)]
wx2 = [w[i]*x2[i] for i in range(n)]
wx1M1 = [w[i]*(x1[i]-M1)**2 for i in range(n)]
wmax = m.Param(value=np.max([w[i] for i in range(n)]))
m.Equation(m.abs3(m.sum(wx1)/n-M1)<=TM1)
m.Equation(m.abs3(m.sum(wx2)/n-M2)<=TM2)
m.Equation(wmax<=2.5)
[m.Equation(w[i]<3.8 for i in range(n))]
m.Equation(m.sum(w)==n)
m.Minimize(m.sum(w2))
m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.solve()

Comment: Here is the (first) error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jonathan.alsop\PycharmProjects\pythonProjectT1\venv\share\Scen1.py", line 27, in <module>
    wmax = m.Param(value=np.max([w[i] for i in range(n)]))

Comment: Please create a new question with that code and the error.

Comment: Hi John, I posted a new question yesterday. Hopefully that's made it clearer. Thanks for your advice.