# Python: Nonlinear optimisation with Gekko

Tags: python, optimization, gekko, restriction, nonlinear-functions

I am getting the following error with the code below:

```py
TypeError: x must be a python list of GEKKO parameters, variables, or expressions
```

The error seems to relate to the form of the "m.Equation" lines.

Many thanks for any help!

Kind regards, Jonathan

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from gekko import GEKKO
x0 = [0,1,2,3,4]
x1 = [5,6,7,8,9]
x2 = [4,3,2,1,0]
y = pd.DataFrame({'x0':x0,'x1':x1,'x2':x2})
x1=y.iloc[:,1]
x2=y.iloc[:,2]

m = GEKKO(remote=False)

M1 = 55.0
TM1 = 0.005
S1=6.0
TS1=0.005
M2 = 0.64
TM2 = 0.0005

n = len(x1)
a0,a1,a2,a3,a4 = m.Array(m.Var,5,lb=-300,ub=300)
b1,b2 = m.Array(m.Var,2,lb=-500,ub=500)
w = m.Intermediate(m.exp(a0+a1*x1+a2*x1**2+a3*x1**3+a4*x1**4 + b1*x2))
m.Equation(m.abs3(m.sum(w*x1)/m.sum(w)-M1)<=TM1)
m.Equation(m.abs3(m.sqrt(m.sum(w*(x1-M1)**2)/(n-1))-S1)<=TS1)
m.Equation(m.abs3(m.sum(w*x2)/m.sum(w)-M2)<=TM2)
m.Equation(m.sum(w)==n)
m.Minimize(m.sum(w**2))
m.solve()

print(a0.value[0],a1.value[0],a2.value[0],a3.value[0],a4.value[0])
print(b1.value[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [Python: Nonlinear optimisation with restrictions (Gekko?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75618720/python-nonlinear-optimisation-with-restrictions-gekko), include an index for each of the data rows in the equations.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from gekko import GEKKO
x0 = [0,1,2,3,4]
x1 = [5,6,7,8,9]
x2 = [4,3,2,1,0]
y = pd.DataFrame({'x0':x0,'x1':x1,'x2':x2})
x1=y.iloc[:,1]
x2=y.iloc[:,2]

m = GEKKO(remote=False)

M1 = 55.0
TM1 = 0.005
S1=6.0
TS1=0.005
M2 = 0.64
TM2 = 0.0005

n = len(x1)
a0,a1,a2,a3,a4 = m.Array(m.Var,5,lb=-300,ub=300)
b1,b2 = m.Array(m.Var,2,lb=-500,ub=500)
w = [m.Intermediate(m.exp(a0+a1*x1[i]
                          +a2*x1[i]**2
                          +a3*x1[i]**3
                          +a4*x1[i]**4
                          + b1*x2[i]))
       for i in range(n)]
w2 = [w[i]**2 for i in range(n)]
wx1 = [w[i]*x1[i] for i in range(n)]
wx2 = [w[i]*x2[i] for i in range(n)]
wx1M1 = [w[i]*(x1[i]-M1)**2 for i in range(n)]
m.Equation(m.abs3(m.sum(wx1)/m.sum(w)-M1)<=TM1)
m.Equation(m.abs3(m.sqrt(m.sum(wx1M1)/(n-1))-S1)<=TS1)
m.Equation(m.abs3(m.sum(wx2)/m.sum(w)-M2)<=TM2)
m.Equation(m.sum(w)==n)
m.Minimize(m.sum(w2))

m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.solve()

print(a0.value[0],a1.value[0],a2.value[0],a3.value[0],a4.value[0])
print(b1.value[0])
```

There is no solution with the sample data, but this may be just because the equations are infeasible with these randomly selected values. If the problem continues to be infeasible, try making `TM1`, `TS1`, and `TM2` variables and minimizing them.

```py
TM1,TS1,TM2 = m.Array(m.Var,3,lb=0)
m.Minimize(TM1+TS1+TM2)
```

This should help it avoid an infeasible solution if the bounds are too tight.

Comment: Many, many thanks for your help here John. It works exactly as I hoped/wished for! Gekko is a fantastic tool - you and the other developers must be extremely proud of it. Where do I send the beer.....? Kind regards, Jonathan

Comment: I'm glad it worked. Thanks for the kind comment. We're always eager to support more undergraduate and graduate students if you know of a company with the resources to sponsor a development project: https://apm.byu.edu/prism/index.php/Main/NewProject